# How to setup cucumber with playwright API testing using typescript

Tags: typescript, cucumber, playwright, cucumberjs, web-api-testing

I am unable to use the GET,POST,PUT any http request when I am using the cucumber with playwright. In the step definition I am trying to use the request.get but it says not a function.  when I create a new context I can do all the operation how to use the playwright config in cucumber for API testing

```
Given("I hit the endpoint {string}", async (request) => {
  const response = await request.get("/metrics", {
    headers: {
      Authorization: auth_token,
    },
  });
  console.log(response);
});

when I create a new context I am able to send request
const context = await request.newContext({
    baseURL: 'https://habitat-energy-development.eu.auth0.com/'
   });
    const response = await context.post('/oauth/token',{
    headers: {
      "Accept": 'application/vnd.github.v3+json',
    },
          data: {
            "grant_type": "password,
            "username":'',
            "password":'',
            "client_id": '',
            "client_secret": '',
            "audience":
          }
      });
      expect(response.ok()).toBeTruthy();`
```